# What would cause a lack of access to wi.gov domains?

Tags: domain, networking

**Problem**

I work in a technical capacity at my job and we recently noticed that we can no longer access wi.gov domains from our network.

One of our clients working for the state of WI (inside a wi.gov domain) also contacted me to inform me that he can no longer reach our website either. My emails via Exchange are also bouncing back as "Delivery Delayed" and then "Delivery Failed". The client's emails are reaching us successfully.

It also seems that wi.us domains are blocked too. Other state .*state*.gov sites work fine. So do federal .gov sites (atf.gov, etc.)

**Troubleshooting Attempts**

In doing some basic troubleshooting we have tried the following:

- Rebooted modem, router, and firewall and checked for any rules that
  might be filtering URLs.
- Contacted our ISP to see if they knew what might
  be causing the block
- Ran a Traceroute to various wi.us and wi.gov
  sites with the following results regardless of .wi address

[image: Traceroute to wi.gov Website]
**Summary (TLDR)**

We can't access wi.gov, wi.us, etc. domains and they can't access us. Our emails are blocked when going to wi.gov email addresses, but they can still email us. We tried a few things and found nothing on our end that we can do, but we did find that a traceroute shows a time out occurring when it hits the UW Wisconsin - Madison (WiscNet) hop.

It seems as if we have been "blacklisted" by the state.

Does anyone know what might be occurring here and how to fix it? How to prevent it from happening in the future?

Thanks in advance for any information you can provide.

Comment: I can get beyond that in a traceroute. I'd probably pick up the phone and call WiscNet.

Comment: It certainly sounds like a problem out there in cloud-land between you and `wi.gov`, but beyond picking up the phone, there's not much you could do.  You could hit up availability testing sites to check on yourself and the `wi.gov` sites you're having trouble with to check how widespread the problem is... but ultimately, that's not going fix it.  For whatever it's worth, I can reach the site for Wisconsin's DOT.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have already contacted WISCNET and they have already told me "not my problem". They did give me a contact email for someone who maybe can help, but they said this is a common problem they get calls about. They can't do anything because they don't administer the firewalls blocking the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted WiscNet and got this sorted out. We support some government health facilities with our software and they apparently didn't like some of the traffic we were sending to our clients for licensing checks, etc.

They directed me to someone else who was able to assist.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue this week.  Just got it solved.  In order to do this, you need to contact the Wisconsin Department of Administration.  Their help desk # is:

608-264-9383